# binary search terminating condition (left != right) vs (left <= right)

Tags: binary-search

I have seen several implementations of binary search where they can use either (left != right) or (left <= right). For example, in normal binary search where you check if target value is in the array, using inclusive right bound (right initially set to array size-1), you will use left <= right. When you want to find the first element larger or equal to target value, you use (left != right). I think my problem is I don't understand the difference between the two. Can someone tell me the intuition of when to pick one condition over the other?

Comment: cs.stackexchange is for questions about computer science, as in the academic discipline. As a rule of thumb, if your question depends on real-life languages/code/hardware/..., ask on Stack Overflow; if your question calls for abstract/mathematical models and reasoning, ask on Computer Science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `left != right` condition, like in the following code sample, where `vec` is a sorted array and `val` is the value we are looking for,

```
int left = 0, right = (int)vec.size();
while(left != right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    if (vec[mid] < val) left = mid + 1;
    else right = mid;
}
```

Both `left` and `right` will in the end denote the least index where `vec[i] >= val` (possibly outside the bounds of the array).

With the `left <= right` condition, like in the following code sample,

```
int left = 0, right = (int)vec.size() - 1;
while(left <= right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    if (vec[mid] < val) left = mid + 1;
    else right = mid - 1;
}
```

`left` will in the end denote the least index where `vec[i] >= val`, and `right` the greatest index where `vec[i] < val` (either possibly outside the bounds of the array).

In my subjective opinion, the difference is so small that it is best to choose one and only ever use it. My preference is the former, as I find it easier to reason about just one value rather than two.